# React-Native Switch uncontrolled using an object doesn't change value

Tags: react-native

I have a `react-native` project in which I'm trying to handle the `Switch` component in a way that I can dynamically set an `object` with the `boolean` and its value, but I doesn't respond well:

Initially I use `useEffect` to process the data:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let lista = {}
    Object.entries(planes).forEach(([j, plan]) => {
      lista[plan.nombre] = false
    })
    setSeleccion(lista)
  }, []);
```

Then I loop through my data to load it and create the "card" dynamically with a `Switch`:

```
<Switch
            offTrackColor="indigo.100"
            onTrackColor="indigo.300"
            onThumbColor="coolgray.500"
            offThumbColor="indigo.50"
            size="lg"
            onToggle={(val) => toggleSwitch(val, plan.nombre)}
            value={seleccion[plan.nombre]}
          />
```

Then toggle function:

```
 const toggleSwitch = (val, plan) => {
   setSeleccion({...seleccion, [plan]: val})
 };
```

Now if I print the new `array` it shows as expected:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(seleccion)
  }, [seleccion]);
```

But sadly the `Switch` remains as `false` visually (just goes back to its false state, so one cant toggle back to off/false).

If I do a `toString(seleccion[plan.nombre])` in the render it shows `[object Undefined]`

Comment: are you using `Switch` from `react-native`?

Comment: yes, actually under the native-base library, but its the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `Switch` that you used is same/from `react-native`. There shouldn't be a prop called `onToggle` in `Switch` like you wrote below.

```js
 <Switch
  offTrackColor="indigo.100"
  onTrackColor="indigo.300"
  onThumbColor="coolgray.500"
  offThumbColor="indigo.50"
  size="lg"
  onToggle={(val) => toggleSwitch(val, plan.nombre)}
  value={seleccion[plan.nombre]}
/>
```

instead, you need to use `onValueChange`

```js
<Switch
  offTrackColor="indigo.100"
  onTrackColor="indigo.300"
  onThumbColor="coolgray.500"
  offThumbColor="indigo.50"
  size="lg"
  onValueChange={(val) => toggleSwitch(val, plan.nombre)}
  value={seleccion[plan.nombre]}
/>
```

You can read more about the `props` in `Switch` [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch#onvaluechange)

Comment: Thank you that worked, I guess forgot to say it was native-base and reading the docs it said onToggle worked for triggering certain things: https://docs.nativebase.io/switch

Comment: oh I read that, I thought it was exactly the same like you said. but based on the docs you share to me I think I know the problem with your code. do you want me to edit the answer?